# Is PXEBooting a way to quickly restore a server?

Tags: pxe

If I used pxelinux and VirtualBox to create a [an image](http://www.howtogeek.com/162809/how-to-pxe-boot-an-ubuntu-image-from-windows-server-2008/) of a machine, and stored it on an NFS share, would it work as a quick way to restore a server that died?

The only part here that keeps confusing me is that usually when PXE booting is involved they talk about how the server that receives the image doesn't have a hard drive.   So typically, do you just make sure that your image is pointing at the correct infrastructure to do writes?  Or redundant infrastructure that you can write to?  Is this only done with certain types of servers?  Do you have to be sure that everything, os and applications fit in the memory of the machine?  Do the servers have to be on a separate vlan to make sure that when some other machine reboots it doesn't receive the image?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. PXE booting is used to build a machine over the network, where said machine has no optical drive or equivalent to use install image on some media. If you are asking to use PXE Boot as the method to boot the machine and start using it, the answer is NO. If you are asking if you can rebuild the machine from the PXE boot image, the answer is YES, but there might be obstacles with network segmentation and nobody but your network admins can answer that part. Your confusing paragraph is really confusing me. The scope is too broad for an answer

Comment: When you say rebuild a machine from an image, that doesn't imply that a machine has or has not media correct?

Comment: If by media, you mean a DVD reader or a USB stick to plug in the installation image, yes. If you mean a totally diskless station NO. WHat you are referring to PXE boot is actually is a very primitive kernel, small enough to transfer over the network in relatively short amount of time. Once it gets loaded and running, it establishes a more capable environment to perform the installation, but not capable enough to operate as a free standing linux server.  I think you are looking for a thin client setup for Linux

Comment: Here are a couple of links for Linux thin clients: http://www.ltsp.org/  and http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-Thin-Clients-a-quick-way-with-Debian-linux/

Comment: So using pxe will only boot a kernel, and not a full blown, fully installed OS?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: PXE boots a special binary called the [Network Bootstrap Program (NBP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment#Overview). A typical NBP would be [PXELINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX); this is a powerful boot loader that can download a Linux kernel/initramfs via TFTP or HTTP. There is no fixed limit on how big and complex the initramfs can be; if your machines have enough memory, you absolutely can put a complete OS in there. A more typical scenario would be a compact bootimage that e.g. installs an OS loaded from the network onto the local disk.

Comment: Also note that PXE is extremely insecure. If you haven't made any precautions like configuring your switches to filter DHCP replies from client ports, anyone in your local network can set up a rogue DHCP server and distribute NBPs to all your computers that are configured to boot via PXE. Especially when you enable PXE on a server you should be very sure that no unauthorized users are able to gain access to your LAN.

Comment: This question is very interesting from an operational point of view.  Could you reformulate it in order not to be closed for being so broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I used pxelinux and VirtualBox to create a an image of a machine, and stored it on an NFS share, would it work as a quick way to restore a server that died?

Yes, this is a possible approach to this problem. You could do this e.g. by using [PXELINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=PXELINUX) as your NBP; PXELINUX could load a compact Linux-based bootimage, and this bootimage could load a hard disk image from a server and write it to the local disk.

I assume that [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/livepxe.php) could be used this way, although I've never tried that myself. Some distributions like [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall), [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer) and probably several others also can be installed by booting the installer via PXE, and you can supply custom configuration for a unattended installation.

There are several problems with this approach though:

- PXE is insecure. Anyone with access to your LAN can set up a rogue DHCP server and distribute PXE NBPs to all computers in your LAN that are configured to boot via PXE. It's usually a bad idea to configure servers to boot via PXE; if your LAN isn't a well isolated management network, you need at the very least to make sure that your switches filter DHCP replies from all normal ports. Also if a PXE bootimage can load your OS image from a server, then so can anyone else... including vital secrets like the `root` password hash.
- You will lose all data and custom configuration from the affected server if you decide to restore this way. If the server doesn't have any important data (e.g. a caching server), then this won't be a big problem, but usually it is. Manually investigating and resolving an issue that prevents the server from working seems preferable to me.
- Imaging is IMO relatively inflexible. If you want to use this for several different servers, than you'll have to maintain several different images, which will possibly take up a lot of space. If you use only a single baseline image, you'll have to manually configure things like the IP address after the recovery. If you've made configuration changes to a server without updating the image, then you'll lose these changes during restore.

Personally, I'd prefer using RAID and backup. The RAID will protect you from downtime when a hard disk fails, and if you lose data, you can restore the system completely (including configuration and data) from the backup. If it fails due to another reason, then investigate and resolve the issue.

Comment: Note that there are two main uses to PXE boot: one is to boot something that installs an OS on the client that you can boot on, the other is to boot an OS that will function without local storage at all (think "thin client").

Comment: yes, Clonezilla can be booted via PXE (and `gpxelinux.0` or `ipxe`). It's a very convenient way of imaging a common SOE to dozens or hundreds of similar workstations (e.g. a computer lab at a university).